# Reduce vertical spacing of paragraph-section

Tags: spacing, koma-script, sections-paragraphs, parskip

How can I reduce the **vertical spacing** from a **paragraph-section** into a **half parskip** on **global** level? I desire the same vertical spacing as `parkskip=half`.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
    \begin{document}
        \chapter{Test}
        \blindtext

        \blindtext
        \paragraph{Half parkskip}
        \blindtext
        \paragraph{Half parkskip}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `beforeskip` for `paragraph` using the KOMA-Script command `\RedeclareSectionCommand`:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp plus 1sp minus -1sp]{paragraph}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\paragraph{Half parkskip}
\blindtext
\paragraph{Half parkskip}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note, that `1sp` is the smallest possible unit (0.00002pt). The `-` sign before `1sp` ensures that there would be no parindent for the first paragraph after the paragraph heading if you decide to remove the `parskip` option and change `afterskip` to a positive value. See the KOMA-Script documentation.